# How to use a periodic function as fill_value with interpolation in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I've been prototyping a phase vocoder in Python.  When shifting up in pitch, I end up with a lot of values outside the interpolation range, and currently that just drops to silence.  I think it might sound better to fill the space with a sine or sawtooth (multiplied by something to get the right amplitude envelope).  Is there a straightforward way of doing this?  I saw that `fill_value` can take an `array_like`, but will it work for that?

EDIT: Just remembered that I couldn't quite do that directly, as this will be in the frequency domain.  Still, is there maybe a way to look at the last so many values in `mag_t`, and kind of copy and scale them appropriately?

In case it helps, this is the relevant snippet of code.  (`fill_value='extrapolate'` is there mostly to avoid error messages.)

```py
    mag_t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=mag.shape[0])
    phase_t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=phase.shape[0])
    
    mag_s = None
    phase_s = None
    
    if isinstance(pitchFactor, np.ndarray):
        #may need to adjust this more in case pitchFactor has 2 or more dimensions?
        #(i.e., to work along the correct axis.)
        ip = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1, num=pitchFactor.shape[0]), pitchFactor,
                      kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
        mag_s = mag_t * ip(mag_t)
        phase_s = phase_t * ip(phase_t)
    else:    
        mag_s = mag_t * pitchFactor
        phase_s = phase_t * pitchFactor

    Ymag = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [ interp1d(mag_s, mag[:,i], fill_value='extrapolate')(mag_t)
             for i in range(mag.ndim) if mag.shape[i] == mag_t.shape[0]
             ]
            )
        )
    
    Yphases = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [ interp1d(phase_s, phase[:,i], fill_value='extrapolate')(phase_t) 
             for i in range(phase.ndim) if phase.shape[i] == phase_t.shape[0]
             ]
            )
        )
```

Comment: Okay, I have something I'm going to try.  I may update this or answer it myself if it works out.

Comment: The thing I tried didn't work great, and I ended up just applying delay to fill the silence.  If anyone has a good answer, though...  (None of the close reasons quite fit.)